# remove duplicates from list based on semantic similarity/relatedness

Tags: r, tm

R + tm: How do I de-duplicate items in a list, based on semantic similarity? 
 `v<-c("bank","banks","banking", "ford_suv',"toyota_suv","nissan_suv")`. My expected solution would be `c("bank", "ford_suv',"toyota_suv","nissan_suv")`. That is, bank, banks and banking to be reduced to one term "bank." `SnowBall::stemming` is not an option because I have to retain the flavor of newspaper styles of various countries. Any help or direction will be useful.

Comment: If you don't despise `for loops`, maybe [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yepnihx03ar2dkx/relatedness.txt?dl=0) can be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We could calculate the Levenshtein distance between words using `adist` and regroup them into clusters using `hclust`

```
d <- adist(v)
rownames(d) <- v
```

Which gives a matrix of distance between terms:

```
#              [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#bank              0    1    3    8    9    8    2   13    6     5     3     4
#banks             1    0    3    7    9    7    2   13    6     6     2     5
#banking           3    3    0    8   10    8    3   13    7     6     3     7
#ford_suv          8    7    8    0    5    6    8   12    7     7     8     4
#toyota_suv        9    9   10    5    0    6    9    7    4     9     9     9
#nissan_suv        8    7    8    6    6    0    8   13   10     4     8    10
#banker            2    2    3    8    9    8    0   12    6     6     1     6
#toyota_corolla   13   13   13   12    7   13   12    0    8    13    12    12
#toyota            6    6    7    7    4   10    6    8    0     6     7     5
#nissan            5    6    6    7    9    4    6   13    6     0     7     6
#bankers           3    2    3    8    9    8    1   12    7     7     0     6
#ford              4    5    7    4    9   10    6   12    5     6     6     0
```

Then we can pass it to `hclust` using `method = ward.D`

```
cl <- hclust(as.dist(d), method  = "ward.D")
plot(cl)
```

Which gives:

[image]

We notice 4 distinct clusters (that we can illustrate using `rect.hclust(cl, 4)`)

[image]

Now, we can turn this result into a `data.frame` and tag each cluster with it's shortest term:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(group = cutree(cl, 4)) %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("term") %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(tag = term[nchar(term) == min(nchar(term))])
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
#Groups: group [4]
#
#             term group      tag
#            <chr> <int>    <chr>
#1            bank     1     bank
#2           banks     1     bank
#3         banking     1     bank
#4        ford_suv     2     ford
#5      toyota_suv     3   toyota
#6      nissan_suv     4   nissan
#7          banker     1     bank
#8  toyota_corolla     3   toyota
#9          toyota     3   toyota
#10         nissan     4   nissan
#11        bankers     1     bank
#12           ford     2     ford
```

Should we want to extract only the unique `tag` for each cluster, we could add `... %>% distinct(tag) %>% .$tag` to the pipe which would give:

```
#[1] "bank"   "ford"   "toyota" "nissan"
```

---

**Reference**

`?adist`

> The (generalized) Levenshtein (or edit) distance between two strings *s*
>   and *t* is the minimal possibly weighted number of insertions, deletions
>   and substitutions needed to transform *s* into *t* (so that the
>   transformation exactly matches *t*).

`?hclust`

> This function performs a hierarchical cluster analysis using a set of
>   dissimilarities for the *n* objects being clustered. Initially, each
>   object is assigned to its own cluster and then the algorithm proceeds
>   iteratively, at each stage joining the two most similar clusters,
>   continuing until there is just a single cluster.

---

**Note**: I used data provided by @Abdou in the comments as it represents a more complete use case

Comment: @Steven +100 internets to you. Fifty for a complete explanation of the underlying logic and 50 for the cross references.

Comment: @Steven: These are frequent terms from `findFreqTerms(dtm[mycluster1[1],],20)` where `mycluster` is `groups <- hclust(dist(m),method="ward.D")
mycluster<-rect.hclust(groups,10) #ten clusters`, is there a way to pipe a `hclust` within the higher `hclust`? Don't want to open another question. Thanks.

Comment: @Pradeep  I'd be happy to help but I'm not sure I follow. Perhaps you could open a new question with a [MCVE] ?

Comment: @Steven: I am working on getting this MWE across to you. annonymization of data is a problem, though.